# User information

Tags: html, mysql

Есть таблицы.Как можно сделать что бы если в поле нет данных пользователя то оно скрывалось,не показывалось ?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="grayinfotypetable">City:</td>
        <td><a>Minsk</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone number:</td>
        <td><span class="grayitem">no no no</span></td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <td>Home number:</td>
        <td><span class="grayitem">no no no</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>skype:</td>
        <td><span class="grayitem"><a
 href="skype:predator_x702?call">predator_x702</a></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Web-site:</td>
        <td><span class="grayitem"><a>http://www.google.com</a></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вытаскивайте из БД записи с определенным условием. Например, выбрать все записи, где имя пользователя не равно "пустота".

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name != ''");
```

Comment: Спасибо,а если имееться ввиду профиль пользователя как в контакте с таким обьемом информации ?(надо вытянуться и вставить в калонки только информацию которую он заполнил и есть в БД,если нет информации для колонки какой нибудь тоесть юзер ее не ввел тогда колонку не показывать) ?

Comment: Способы зависят от структуры БД. Если вы храните всю инфу о пользователе в одной таблице, что не всега гуд, то придется проверять каждую переменную на пустоту. Поэтому, я думаю, что тут надо две таблицы. Например, **users** и **user_info**. В  **user_info**, в каждой строке, храните id пользователя из первой таблицы, второе поле - название информации (или город, или телефон и т.д.), а в тртьем поле - соответственно значение: Минск, 02 etc.

Comment: P.S. Могу предположить, что у вас возникнет сложность с тем, как добавлять/апдейтить поля в таблице **user_info**. Надеюсь, что с MySQL-запросами дружите, тогда смотрите в сторону конструкции "**INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...**".

Comment: @Deonis в обычном sql в user_info одним batch'ем сначала удаляют все данные по пользователю, потом пишут новые, тогда не нужен duplicate key udpate, и не нужно дополнительных телодвижений по поводу очистки полей.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, в общем-то да. Можно и таким образом .

----------

Можно перефразировать ответ @AlexWindHope 

> спорить с 35 летним программистом гнилое занятие ...

... когда самому уже аж 37 )))